# Can't run Python code in Visual Studio Code with Jupyter - "Jupyter kernel cannot be started from 'Python 3.6.8 64-bit"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've installed Jupyter extension in the latest Visual Studio:
Visual Studio 1.3.01 64
Jupyter 1.1.4

As I am using tensorflow I need Python 3 64bit.

When I try to run simple code I get:

```
Jupyter kernel cannot be started from 'Python 3.6.8 64-bit ('tensorflow64': virtualenv)'. Using closest match Python 3.7.0 32-bit instead.
```

Code:

```
#%%
import tensorflow as tf

session = tf.Session()

hello = tf.constant("Hello from Milan.")
print(session.run(hello))

a = tf.constant(20)
b = tf.constant(22)

print('a + b = {0}'.format(session.run(a + b)))
```

All works fine if I Run code not using Jupyter from VS Code.

Comment: You should format the error on your Question too. Anyways, can you verify the kernels you have by `jupyter kernelspec list` and `import platform 
print(platform.python_version())` to see which version of python does VSCode use

Comment: this is an extension for VS Code so couldn't find jupyter.exe, bat, .... the other command will gave me ('64bit', 'WindowsPE') 3.7.0. I think the issue might be with missing packages Jupyter requires from python virt env. Will try this one: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3579

Comment: Make sense, seems you don't have jupyter install on the current python env that vscode is looking at. You can simply install the package via pip command `pip3 install jupyter` or `py -3 -m pip install jupyter` via powershell or any command line shell you.re using.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Message from Jupyter is not the best description of the issue, missing ipykernel package.

Fix was to install additional python package 'ipykernel' into virtual environment with Python 3.64 bit.

```
pip install ipykernel
```

Additional info:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3579

Answer (score 1):

```
conda create --name test_env
conda activate test_env
conda install -c anaconda ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=test_env
```

Or this You can run this it might work

```
ipython kernel install --user --name=ENVNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple installation is the best. While learning Python et-all I had installed many things in many different ways. It was a mess. Removed everything and did a fresh install only I used pyenv and pipenv. However pipenv does not work with the latest version which you can install using brew. Solution revert back to version 2018.10.13 using pip install. Then I discovered that pipenv was no longer recommended so, I removed it. Built a test project and could not get jupyter to run. Spent all day trying everything.

Solution was, remove the old version of pipenv and install the latest using brew. All is well.

However, I do like the features of pyenv like setting global etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select and save the .ipynb file with VSCode indicating a kernel that is reachable from your Jupyter installation:

[image]

Comment: Here is shown "busy" and when I click on it, there's no options for Kernel. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In my case installing anaconda and call following comments solves it:

`conda create -n tf tensorflow`
`conda activate tf`